# WIF (wallet import format) to bitcoin address converter

Tags: python

**I wrote a script that converts private keys (hex format) to WIF,PUB-Address (compressed and uncompressed) I think my code if right but when i run it it throws me an error and I don't understand what im doing wrong**

```
import binascii, hashlib, base58, sys, ecdsa, codecs
arq1 = open('list-WIF-Uncompressed.txt', 'w')
arq2 = open('list-WIF-Compressed.txt', 'w')
arq3 = open('list-Addresses-Uncompressed.txt', 'w')
arq4 = open('list-Addresses-Compressed.txt', 'w')
arq5 = open('list-AllOrdened.txt', 'w')

arq5.write("      Address Uncompressed          |        Address Compressed           |                    Private Key WIF                   |              Private Key WIF Compressed \n")

def convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Uncompressed(z):
    private_key_static = z
    extended_key = "80"+private_key_static
    first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(extended_key)).hexdigest()
    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()
    final_key = extended_key+second_sha256[:8]
    WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key))
    print("Private Key WIF Uncompress: " + WIF)
    arq1.write("%s \n" % WIF)
    arq5.write("%s    " % WIF)

def convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Compressed(z):
    private_key_static = z
    extended_key = "80"+private_key_static+'01'
    first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(extended_key)).hexdigest()
    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()
    final_key = extended_key+second_sha256[:8]
    WIFc = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key))
    print("Private Key WIF Compressed: " + WIFc)
    arq2.write("%s \n" % WIFc)
    arq5.write("%s    \n" % WIFc)



def conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed(z):

    zk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(z.decode('hex'), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    zk_verify = zk.verifying_key

    z_public_key = ('\04' + zk.verifying_key.to_string()).encode('hex')
   
    #first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(z_public_key)).hexdigest()

    ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(z_public_key.decode('hex')).digest())
    ripemd160_result = ripemd160.hexdigest()
    step3 =  '00' + ripemd160_result
    
    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(step3)).hexdigest()

    third_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(second_sha256)).hexdigest()

    step6 = third_sha256[:8]

    step7 = step3+step6

    bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(step7))
    print("Bitcoin Address Uncompress: " + bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)
    arq3.write("%s \n" % bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)
    arq5.write("%s    " % bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)

def conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_compressed(z):

    pvk_to_bytes = codecs.decode (z, 'hex')
   

    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string (pvk_to_bytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
    key_bytes = key.to_string()
    key_hex = codecs.encode(key_bytes, 'hex')

    if(ord(bytearray.fromhex(key_hex[-2:])) % 2 == 0):

        public_key_compressed = '02' + key_hex[0:64]

        #Making SHA-256 of pubkey compressed and making RIPEMD-160 of this
        public_key_in_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed, 'hex')
        sha256_public_key_compressed = hashlib.sha256(public_key_in_bytes)
        sha256_public_key_compressed_digest = sha256_public_key_compressed.digest()

        ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
        ripemd160.update(sha256_public_key_compressed_digest)
        ripemd160_digest = ripemd160.digest()
        ripemd160_hex = codecs.encode(ripemd160_digest, 'hex')

        #Adding network bytes 0x00
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network = b'00' + ripemd160_hex
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network, 'hex')

        #Making Checksum for MainNet, this is SHA-256 2x turns and get the firsts 4 bytes
        sha256_one = hashlib.sha256(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes)
        sha256_one_digest = sha256_one.digest()
        sha256_two = hashlib.sha256(sha256_one_digest)
        sha256_two_digest = sha256_two.digest()
        sha256_2_hex = codecs.encode(sha256_two_digest, 'hex')
        checksum = sha256_2_hex[:8]

        bitcoin_compressed_address_hex = (public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network + checksum).decode('utf-8')
        bitcoin_compressed_address = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(bitcoin_compressed_address_hex))
        arq4.write("%s \n" % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        arq5.write("%s    " % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        print("Bitcoin Address Compressed: " + bitcoin_compressed_address)

    else:
        #The last byte of value for Y is Odd, this require add '03' at first

        public_key_compressed = '03' + key_hex[0:64]

        #Making SHA-256 of pubkey compressed and making RIPEMD-160 of this
        public_key_in_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed, 'hex')
        sha256_public_key_compressed = hashlib.sha256(public_key_in_bytes)
        sha256_public_key_compressed_digest = sha256_public_key_compressed.digest()

        ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
        ripemd160.update(sha256_public_key_compressed_digest)
        ripemd160_digest = ripemd160.digest()
        ripemd160_hex = codecs.encode(ripemd160_digest, 'hex')

        #Adding network bytes 0x00
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network = b'00' + ripemd160_hex
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network, 'hex')

        #Making Checksum for MainNet, this is SHA-256 2x turns and get the firsts 4 bytes
        sha256_one = hashlib.sha256(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes)
        sha256_one_digest = sha256_one.digest()
        sha256_two = hashlib.sha256(sha256_one_digest)
        sha256_two_digest = sha256_two.digest()
        sha256_2_hex = codecs.encode(sha256_two_digest, 'hex')
        checksum = sha256_2_hex[:8]

        bitcoin_compressed_address_hex = (public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network + checksum).decode('utf-8')
        bitcoin_compressed_address = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(bitcoin_compressed_address_hex))
        arq4.write("%s \n" % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        arq5.write("%s    " % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        print("Bitcoin Address Compressed: " + bitcoin_compressed_address)
 

with open("brute-pvks.txt") as file:
    for line in file:

        pvk_hexadecimal = str.strip(line)
        print("__________________________________________________\n")
        print("Converting pvk: " + pvk_hexadecimal)
        
        conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
        conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_compressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
        convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Uncompressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
        convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Compressed(pvk_hexadecimal)        



print("__________________________________________________\n")
```

**I input the private keys in raw hex format when I run this it throws me this error I don't understand what this means**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\pub>python mega-tool-pvkmassconvert.py
__________________________________________________

Converting pvk: 0081DD3ADE2A43A48B85ECE267C3A18E10C90AEF0166D71F3E95FC51C99EF801
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pull\numbers\pub\mega-tool-pvkmassconvert.py", line 170, in <module>
    conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\pull\numbers\pub\mega-tool-pvkmassconvert.py", line 52, in conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed
    zk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(z.decode('hex'), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: z is a str object so you need to convert it to a byte object and then decode it. When you use decode you should pass in what you want to decode to not the string or byte object.  `bytes.fromhex(z).decode("ASCII")`

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```py
import binascii, hashlib, base58, sys, ecdsa, codecs
import os

arq1 = open('list-WIF-Uncompressed.txt', 'w')
arq2 = open('list-WIF-Compressed.txt', 'w')
arq3 = open('list-Addresses-Uncompressed.txt', 'w')
arq4 = open('list-Addresses-Compressed.txt', 'w')
arq5 = open('list-AllOrdened.txt', 'w')

arq5.write(
    "Address Uncompressed          |        Address Compressed           |                    Private Key WIF         "
    "          |              Private Key WIF Compressed \n")


def convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Uncompressed(z):
    private_key_static = z
    extended_key = "80" + private_key_static
    first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(extended_key)).hexdigest()
    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()
    final_key = extended_key + second_sha256[:8]
    WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key)).decode('utf-8')
    print("Private Key WIF Uncompressed: " + WIF)
    arq1.write("%s \n" % WIF)
    arq5.write("%s    " % WIF)


def convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Compressed(z):
    private_key_static = z
    extended_key = "80" + private_key_static + '01'
    first_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(extended_key)).hexdigest()
    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(first_sha256)).hexdigest()
    final_key = extended_key + second_sha256[:8]
    WIFc = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(final_key)).decode('utf-8')
    print("Private Key WIF Compressed: " + WIFc)
    arq2.write("%s \n" % WIFc)
    arq5.write("%s    \n" % WIFc)



def conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed(z):
    zk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(codecs.decode(z, 'hex'), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    zk_verify = zk.verifying_key

    z_public_key = b'\x04' + zk.verifying_key.to_string()

    ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    ripemd160.update(hashlib.sha256(z_public_key).digest())
    ripemd160_result = ripemd160.hexdigest()
    step3 = '00' + ripemd160_result

    second_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(step3)).hexdigest()

    third_sha256 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(second_sha256)).hexdigest()

    step6 = third_sha256[:8]

    step7 = step3 + step6

    bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(step7)).decode('utf-8')
    print("Bitcoin Address Uncompressed: " + bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)
    arq3.write("%s \n" % bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)
    arq5.write("%s    " % bitcoin_uncompressed_address_std)


def conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_compressed(z):
    pvk_to_bytes = codecs.decode(z, 'hex')

    key = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(pvk_to_bytes, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1).verifying_key
    key_bytes = key.to_string()
    key_hex = codecs.encode(key_bytes, 'hex').decode('utf-8')

    if ord(bytearray.fromhex(key_hex[-2:])) % 2 == 0:
        public_key_compressed = '02' + key_hex[0:64]
    else:
        public_key_compressed = '03' + key_hex[0:64]

        # Making SHA-256 of pubkey compressed and making RIPEMD-160 of this
        public_key_in_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed, 'hex')
        sha256_public_key_compressed = hashlib.sha256(public_key_in_bytes)
        sha256_public_key_compressed_digest = sha256_public_key_compressed.digest()

        ripemd160 = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
        ripemd160.update(sha256_public_key_compressed_digest)
        ripemd160_digest = ripemd160.digest()
        ripemd160_hex = codecs.encode(ripemd160_digest, 'hex')

        # Adding network bytes 0x00
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network = b'00' + ripemd160_hex
        public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes = codecs.decode(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network, 'hex')

        # Making Checksum for MainNet, this is SHA-256 2x turns and get the firsts 4 bytes
        sha256_one = hashlib.sha256(public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network_bytes)
        sha256_one_digest = sha256_one.digest()
        sha256_two = hashlib.sha256(sha256_one_digest)
        sha256_two_digest = sha256_two.digest()
        sha256_2_hex = codecs.encode(sha256_two_digest, 'hex')
        checksum = sha256_2_hex[:8]
        bitcoin_compressed_address_hex = (public_key_compressed_bitcoin_network + checksum).decode('utf-8')

        bitcoin_compressed_address = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(bitcoin_compressed_address_hex)).decode(
            'utf-8')
        arq4.write("%s \n" % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        arq5.write("%s    " % bitcoin_compressed_address)
        print("Bitcoin Address Compressed: " + bitcoin_compressed_address)


pvk_hexadecimal: str = os.urandom(32).hex()
print("__________________________________________________\n")
print("Converting pvk: " + pvk_hexadecimal)

conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_uncompressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
conv_pvkhex_to_bitcoinaddress_compressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Uncompressed(pvk_hexadecimal)
convert_pvk_Hex_to_WIF_Compressed(pvk_hexadecimal)

print("__________________________________________________\n")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).